# Replace href attribute onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the `href` attribute when a user clicks on a link. I'm using a script called [stylesheetswitcher](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm) to switch CSS styles and would like to jump between 2 styles while clicking one link.

Here is the link HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('style1')"">switch style</a>
```

**I want the `href` change to "style2" when clicked.**

Comment: 1. Putting code in href is bad. 2. There is a useless quote 3. `javascript:chooseStyle('style1');this.href = "javascript:chooseStyle('style2');"` 4. Why do you want to that? You should better save the state into a variable.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the style into the function? why can't the function handle that itself since you aren't allowing the user to specify which style to change to?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry for my bad wording, I intend to toggle two .css files to change the sites theme. For that I made use of styleswitcher JS and was wondering how to use one link to toggle between 2 styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated answer:

Thanks for clarifying your requirements.

As mentioned on the page for [styleswitcher JS](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm), there are only a few things you need to do to get this working:

### You need to assign `title` attributes to your `<link>` tags in your head

Let's say you have the following stylesheet links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
```

You need to mark them by adding `title` attributes, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" title="style1">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" title="style2">
```

### Write yourself a style swapping function

```
function swapStyles () {
    if ( this.getAttribute('data-active-style').value === 'style1' ) {
        // Switch styles
        chooseStyle('style2',30);
        // Set the active style
        this.setAttribute('data-active-style','style2');
    } else {
        // Switch styles
        chooseStyle('style1',30);
        // Set the active style
        this.setAttribute('data-active-style','style1');
    }
    return this;
}
```

### Add an event listener to your `<a>`

You can do this with the HTML `onclick` attribute

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="swapStyles()">switch styles</a>
```

Or, you can add an event listener in Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
    swapStyles();
}, true);
```

---

## [Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xw8g/2/)

It's better to make something like a toggle function, like so:

```
function toggleStyle () {
    if ( this.className.indexOf('style1') > -1 )
        this.className = 'style2';
    else
        this.className = 'style1';
}
```

Also, you should take that Javascript out of the `href` attribute. Instead, add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) in your Javascript:

```
function toggleStyle () {
    if ( this.className.indexOf('style1') > -1 )
        this.className = 'style2';
    else
        this.className = 'style1';
}

// Wait for window to load
window.onload = function () {

    // Add event listener
    document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].addEventListener('click', toggleStyle, true);

};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! And sorry for my bad wording, I intend to toggle two .css files to change the sites theme. For that I made use of [styleswitcher JS](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm) and was wondering how to use one link to toggle between 2 styles.